# tensorflow initialize local variable with delay

Tags: python, tensorflow

My database is a nested folder of images. I am using os.walk and slice input producer to create a filename queue which is fed to whole file readers.

The code works fine on a small subset of my database (when the crawling is fast). But throws "**out of range**" error on a whole one. For a larger database the issue can be solved by setting epoch counter to None.

Is there a way to initialize variable with delay/dependencies ?

The minimal example of code is below:

```
ligand_file_list,receptor_file_list = index_the_database(database_path)

ligand_files = tf.convert_to_tensor(ligand_file_list,dtype=tf.string)
receptor_files = tf.convert_to_tensor(receptor_file_list,dtype=tf.string)

filename_queue = tf.train.slice_input_producer([ligand_files,receptor_files],num_epochs=10,shuffle=True)

serialized_ligand = tf.read_file(filename_queue[0])
serialized_receptor = tf.read_file(filename_queue[1])

init_two = tf.initialize_all_variables()
init_one = tf.initialize_local_variables()
sess = tf.Session()
coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess,coord=coord)
sess.run([init_one])
sess.run([init_two])

while True:
    print sess.run([serialized_ligand,serialized_receptor])
```

Comment: You can use `time.sleep()`. Your `tf.convert_to_tensor` call produces a fixed list, so you need to make sure your file lists are complete before calling that function

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov - thank you for a proposed solution. I checked my dynamic shape of tensor of filenames with tf.shape(ligand_files). The list is complete every time.  The error I am getting is different: Failed precondition: Attempting to use uninitialized value Variable... class=["loc:@Variable"]. Problem gets much worse (90%) of the time if I use tf.train.batch with multiple threads

Comment: you could probably get an answer to that if you posted a fully reproducible example as a separate question